Is plot_pacf bugged, or am I misinterpreting?
Working with univariate time series, and pacf and plot_pacf look like they disagree.
data = pd.DataFrame([92.525053,94.143395,94.411914
,93.575748,91.589286,90.287014,94.079157
,87.876495,87.574407,89.111282,85.079154
,87.681434,85.405918,85.908849,84.671726
,86.082699,83.533036,84.711062,85.938864
,81.183803,84.570561,84.159882,83.185892
,84.634064,84.782505,86.057603,85.854435])

plot_pacf(data, lags = 12, alpha = .05)
pacf(data, nlags = 12, alpha = .05)

The output values from the function don't appear to match to the plot.
Pacf gives values and confidence intervals. A little calculation says that the confidence interval for every value has a radius of about .377.
My understanding was that this means the light blue bar on plot_pacf should shade from -.377 to .377 (because plot_pacf centers the interval on zero).
Consider the third value (index = 2) given by the pacf function. Pacf function says value is .396. This should be outside the shaded area shown on plot_pacf. Yet the plot clearly shows that bar wholly contained in the shaded interval area.
Similarly, consider the fifth value (index = 4) given by the pacf function. Pacf function says value is -.459. This should definitely be outside the shaded area shown on plot_pacf. Yet the plot clearly shows that bar wholly contained in the shaded interval area.
Is there a problem with the library? Or am I misunderstanding the values, the confidence interval numbers, or the plot?
